# How to append a list in Python based on condition?

Tags: python, list, append

I am having trouble in appending a list. Following is the code:

```
score_Resp = 0
score_O2Sat = 5
score_SBP = 0
score_HR = 1
score_Temp = 0

Abnormal = []
if score_Resp != 0:
    Abnormal.append("Resp")
elif score_O2Sat != 0:
    Abnormal.append("O2Sat")
elif score_SBP != 0:
    Abnormal.append("SBP")
elif score_HR != 0:
    Abnormal.append("HR")
elif score_Temp != 0:
    Abnormal.append("Temp")
else:
    print("Invalid Statement!")
print("Abnormal Vitals:", Abnormal)
```

The output:

```
Abnormal Vitals: ['O2Sat']
```

when it should be:

```
Abnormal Vitals: ['O2Sat', 'HR']
```

Can someone help me what went wrong? And also, can someone refine the code with less code? Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using `elif`. Just plain `ifs` to evaluate each and every condition.

Like this:

```
if score_Resp != 0:
    Abnormal.append("Resp")
if score_O2Sat != 0:
    Abnormal.append("O2Sat")
if score_SBP != 0:
    Abnormal.append("SBP")
if score_HR != 0:
    Abnormal.append("HR")
if score_Temp != 0:
    Abnormal.append("Temp")
```

The `elif` clause is a `else if`. So, when your code evaluates to `True` the first one, it just ignores the rest. That's why you are not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
score_Resp = 0
score_O2Sat = 5
score_SBP = 0
score_HR = 1
score_Temp = 0

Abnormal = []
if score_Resp != 0:
    Abnormal.append("Resp")
if score_O2Sat != 0:
    Abnormal.append("O2Sat")
if score_SBP != 0:
    Abnormal.append("SBP")
if score_HR != 0:
    Abnormal.append("HR")
if score_Temp != 0:
    Abnormal.append("Temp")

print("Abnormal Vitals:", Abnormal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it only if you go through every condition and want to check it.

```py
score_Resp = 0
score_O2Sat = 5
score_SBP = 0
score_HR = 1
score_Temp = 0

Abnormal = []
if score_HR != 0:
    Abnormal.append("HR")
if score_O2Sat != 0:
    Abnormal.append("O2Sat")
if score_SBP != 0:
    Abnormal.append("SBP")
if score_Resp != 0:
    Abnormal.append("Resp")
if score_Temp != 0:
    Abnormal.append("Temp")

print("Abnormal Vitals:", Abnormal)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).